# Order categories by sum of custom fields

Tags: custom-field

I use `get_terms` to display some categories. I also use a custom field `_postviews` to count the views per post.

I want to order these categories by sum of the custom field. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$terms = get_terms( array(

            'taxonomy'   => 'category',
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ) );
        $sort  = array();
        //loop to list through all category
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $id    = $term->ID;
            $name  = $term->name;
            $args  = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'category'  => $name,

            );

            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
            $sum   = 0;
            if ($query->have_posts() ):while ($query->have_posts() ):$query->the_post();
                // to add all the values of the custom field

                $sum += get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_postviews ', true );
            endwhile;
                //adds term name and the total sum of all _postviews meta in array the term name as key abnd the sum as its value
                $sort[ $name ] = $sum;
            endif;
            //sort keys based on values HIGH TO LOW


        }
 arsort( $sort );       
 print_r( $sort );
```

Theoretically the above code should work as

1. It loops through your category
2. Gets post based on your category
3. Get post most meta and store add them in the variable sum
4. Once all the post have been checked and stored in a variable sum, they are        now stored as array in the variable $sort

Could you please let me know if this code worked for you or not

Comment: thank you for your answer but it didn't work for me. What I want to do is to sum the views from all posts for each category. Although I don't know if this is the most performance efficient solution.

Comment: a quick question is doest  the post  meta `_postviews` stores all total view count for a post.?

Comment: Yes it stores all total view count for a post.

Comment: So basically  `$sum += get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_postviews ', true );` should give you a total sum value of all the post that is in a cateogry if not could you replace `$sum += get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_postviews ', true );`  `$sum =$sum + get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_postviews ', true );`

Comment: Also  `arsort( $sort );` is used to store the values based on values